# How to add an outlet to a 4 way switch (DPDT)

Tags: switches, dpdt, spdt

Situation:

I am a once in never tinker when coming to electricity.

I have one lamp being controlled by 3 light switch.
So I must have 2 SPDT (3 way switch) and one DPDT (4 way switch).

I am looking to have a power outlet by one of the switch.

Moving from:

[image]

To:

[image]

The issue I have is that the switch I am willing to replace is in reality the DPDT.
[image]

I believe this is not possible without bringing the neutral all the way to the DPDT.
Below is a quick sketch if what I understand.

Question:

Is there a handy way to have a power outlet by my 4 way switch?

[image]

Comment: it depends how your 4-way is wired. It need not have a neutral already there, but it may do.

Comment: I think you might want to re-evaluate your "this should work!" arrangement. You're shorting out the leftmost switch, so only the middle and right switches will actually function to turn the light on and off; the left one does nothing. You need to bring both live and neutral separately to the switch box if you want an outlet there.

Comment: Options 1, 2, 3 & 4 short out all the switches. The light will be on no matter what switch combination you select and the two pins of the socket will be at the same voltage so there will be 0 V difference at the socket pins. As already mentioned, option 5 shorts out the left switch so it can no longer control the light. You may be advised to check that adding a socket to a lighting circuit is allowed in your area's wiring regulations.

Comment: My first concern is the legality of what you are doing. In many jurisdictions you are not allowed to work on residential mains wiring unless you are a trained electrican. Do call a trained electrician to add the mains receptacles for you, if you are not confident you are able to install those yourself safely and according to rules of local electrical codes and laws.

Comment: I would say to wire completely around the first switch (on the left in your diagram) and replace the second switch with one that has a RF remote control.  Otherwise, I recommend moving this to DIY since your relevant electrical code will probably have something to say about this.

Comment: this question belongs at https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions ... none of the first four diagrams will work ... the lamp will always be on and the power plug will be short-circuited ... it will have voltage between ground and the power prongs only

Comment: First of all thanks a lot you all. @Justme, yeah I should take a few step back a check if I am even allowed to do that. @ Hearth and @ Transistor, yep 1,2,3,4 are the same situation with different switches position, which led me to understand the flow in my initial idea. 5 was my idea to work around it. Anyway as I say before I might need to check the legality of what I am doing here ^^. Cheers everyone one less dude being zapped :)

Comment: 5th circuit will have a functioning power outlet and a lamp that is always lit, and it will not be to code because you have one wire on one side of the circuit and two wires on the other side

Comment: Yep, I see it now. Glad I didn't do anything.